# Receiving import error when trying to open project of solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to open a solution with 4 projects. Two of the projects are giving me the error:

> Error: The value "" of "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid. Parameter "path" cannot have zero length.

Here are the two 'import' tags that I could find in my file. I have searched for them online, but I could not find any information.

Any ideas to how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your project file got corrupted or modified by hand.

Here is an example of what one of my project files looks like. You could try either fixing the  `<Import Project=` or attempt to just remove the node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
  .....
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```